# Accuracy of time series predicton

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have two time series - actual and predicted. They both can be positive or negative, can jump or remain constant, one can be positive other can be negative - basically any combination is possible depending on how good the prediction is.

I am looking for a reasonable way to represent how accurate my prediction is. I am mainly interested in predicting extreme moves. Preferably a single number that I can use to quantify the accuracy. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Root Mean Squared Error is made for extreme moves, penalized large error more than small ones.

Comment: Would you be able to specify a loss function associated with the prediction errors? That would imply an accuracy measure.